# Como saber la duracion de un video mp4 en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, vlcj

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de audio y video, con la interfaz que estoy trabajando es EmbeddedMediaPlayer de la libreria vlcj. Si alguien sabe como podria saber la duracion total de un video en java.

Aqui el link de los metodos de la interfaz: http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.1.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/embedded/EmbeddedMediaPlayer.html

Aqui el codigo:

```
Canvas c=new Canvas();
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:/ProgramFiles/VideoLAN/VLC");    
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        MediaPlayerFactory mpf=new MediaPlayerFactory();
        emp=mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(this));
        emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(c));
        emp.prepareMedia("Video.mp4");
        emp.play();
```

Comment: Podrías incluir el código relativo a la pregunta?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para agilizar una respuesta que ayude a resolver tu problema conviene que llames siempre a cada cosa por su nombre. No es lo mismo decir *con la interfaz que estoy trabajando*  a decir *estoy trabajando con la interfaz / librería / paquete tal*. Otra cosa que exigen las normas de este sitio es que muestres un ejemplo del código fallido. Tu pregunta debería ser mejorada editándola para incorporar esa información.

Comment: Ya he agregdo el codigo y el link de los metodos de la interfaz, disculpen.

Comment: Parece ser que el método [**`getLength`**](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.1.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/MediaPlayer.html#getLength()) te devuelve la duración en milisegundos. ¿Probaste esa posibilidad? Luego sería cuestión de convertir los milisengundos en horas:minutos:segundos si fuera necesario.

Comment: @A.Cedano He probado el metodo getLength y me devuelve la longitud de ese momento especifico, y no he podido obtener el tiempo total

Comment: Si es un vídeo que se está reproduciendo, entonces puedes revisar lo que consigues con métodos como [**`getMediaDetails()`**](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.1.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/MediaPlayer.html#getMediaDetails()) o alguno de los métodos relativos a los metadatos como **`getMediaMeta()`**

Comment: Lo probare ahora brother

Comment: Borther lo probe con los metodos relacionados con los metadatos y aun nada, cuando utilize el metodo emp.getMediaMeta().getLength() me devuelve un -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que tu MediaPlayer no tiene la información de la duración del vídeo hasta que no ha comenzado la reproducción.
Si ejecutas el método `getLength()` justo tras ejecutar el método `play()`, el vídeo aún no habrá comenzado a reproducirse, y por tanto al no disponer de la información de la duración, el método `getLength()` devuelve -1.

Para obtener la duración del vídeo, puedes hacerlo de varias formas. Yo te dejo dos que se me han ocurrido, una con eventos y otra con hilos.

Para los dos casos el vídeo que he descargado el siguiente [vídeo](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_video.asp)

**Obtener duración mediante eventos**

Importa lo siguiente a tu clase:

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayer; 
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerEventAdapter;
```

Añade un eventLister del tipo `MediaPlayerEventAdapter` a tu objeto `EmbeddedMediaPlayer`

```
emp.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter()
{   
    @Override
    public void playing(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
    {
        System.out.println("Duracion: " + (long)mediaPlayer.getMediaMeta().getLength() / 1000);
    }
});
```

**Obtener duración usando un hilo:**

Hilo.java

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;

public class Hilo implements Runnable{
    long len;
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer player = null;

    public Hilo(EmbeddedMediaPlayer player){
        this.player = player;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Dormimos el hilo para asegurarnos que la reproducción ha comenzado
            // Pongo 1 segundo para que veas el funcionamiento. El tiempo lo tienes que ajustar
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            // Calculamos el tiempo del video en segundos.
            len = (long)player.getMediaMeta().getLength() / 1000;
            System.out.println(len);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

En tu clase principal:

```
...

MediaPlayerFactory mpf=new MediaPlayerFactory();
emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(this));
emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(c));

// Instanciamos el hilo 
Runnable hilo = new Hilo(emp);

emp.prepareMedia("Video.mp4");
emp.play();

// Lanzamos el hilo
new Thread(hilo).start();
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias brother, lo he resuelto agregando el evento.